# Edit custom style of TButton in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

In my **Firemonkey HD** application I have to edit the default style of a TButton.
Opening the TStyleBook resources I've seen that the TLayout object of each buttons have two different sub-components:

- - TSubImage (it set the default background image for each component)
- - TText     (it shows the text)

When I try to add a TPanel, TRectangle or TImage to my TLayout I see that, after saving and applying the changes, running my application the **OnClick** event of my TButton doesn't work.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the HitTest property of any components you add which you do not want to respond to mouse clicks and gestures.